# trace movie clip end

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, event-handling

Hi i have navigation menu animated click it pops up from corner to center click its gone and `gotoandplay('page2')` is triggered. while page loads menu goes away.

So my point is i want to show page title only after menu is gone (menu clip stopped playing) this works but menu is child MC i try put

```
var showtitle:Boolean = false;
if(showtitle==true){
timelineheader.visible = true;
} else {
timelineheader.visible=false;
};
```

inside page2 keyframe and then trigger `MovieClip(root).showtitle=true`; but it does not work is there way to make it work?

Perhaps i could use

```
  trace("SubMC_Ended");
```

but how i build event handler that constantly checks for this message?

Answer (score 0):

Just set up a enterFrame handler and see if movieclip.currentFrame == movieclip.totalFrames